# FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE is not working as expected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions, fragmenttransaction

How can I switch to another fragment without any animation?

I have two fragments and show/hide them using this:

```
supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .hide(currentFragment)
    .show(selectedFragment)
    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE)
    .commit()
```

I expect them to switch without any animation, but there is a fade animation.

[image]

If I set the transition to `TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE`, The fade animation will be shorter:
[image]

I'm using `androidx` version `1.6.0-alpha02` and `kotlin` version `1.4.32`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

It was because of Shared Element `Transition` that was setting in `onCreate`.

```
sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)
```

Removing this line fixed the problem.

However I wonder in case of having a shared element transition, how can I navigate to another fragment without fading animation...

Answer (score 0):

`FragmentTransactions` sets the animation for a fragment `entering` or `exiting` the transaction.

`show()`: displays a previously hidden fragment. This is only relevant for fragments that have been added to the container. Show will use the FragmentTransaction that was used when the Fragment originally entered the container.

`hide()`: Hides the existing fragment. This is only relevant for fragments whose views have been added to a container, as this will cause the view to be hidden. Hide will use the FragmentTransaction that was set when the fragment originally entered the trasaction.

In your case when you call FragmentTransaction, it isn't setting the animation because you don't have a fragment entering or exiting the container, you are using hide and show to display your fragment so the FragmentTransaction is using the animation for when the fragments had originally entered the container.

If you wish to control the animation I would suggest using `replace` instead of `show` and hide`.

Comment: If that's the case, changing the transition mode should not effect the animation but it does! I've also tried the example transition for `add`, `replace` and other possible actions but the result was the same.

Comment: Have you tried using a version of the library that isn't in the testing phase?

Comment: I just tried `androidx` version `1.3.2` that was introduced as latest stable version in google documentations but the result is the same.